# How can I style a ListPicker to behave just like the native ListPick in the OS settings pages?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am using the ListPicker from the toolkit. I have managed to apply a style template so that when the user is selecting from a list of items in fullscreen mode, it looks somewhat similar to the native WP7 implementation.

However, there are a few things missing that appear on the native implementation:

1. On full mode enter, the items appear via an animation
2. When at item is selected, it stays highlighted for an instant, then the items disappear via an animation

Am I missing something or is this simply just not exposed to 3rd party developers using silverlight at this point in time?

Comment: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Working-with-WP7-ListPicker-SelectedItem will this help?

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that won't help. what i am asking is how to get the animations working; the actual selection and data mechanism works just fine out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations are provided in November Toolkit. Download the latest version, please

Answer (score 0):

Check the other posts in the same site .. http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-customize-the-listpicker-selected-item